# Need help in optimizing the below helper class

Tags: trigger, class, performance, after-trigger

Logic : 
For any new record inserts for 'Properties' object, check if its Account_Ref_Ext_ID__c equals to 'Account' object's  Chris_Account_Number__c. If it matches, assign Account id to properties  object's  provider__c field

```
public class Properties_TriggerHelper {
public static void lookupAccount(List<Properties__c> newPropertiesList, Map<Id,Properties__c> newMap)  {
    List<Properties__c> PropToUpdate = new List<Properties__c>();   

     for (Properties__c P : newPropertiesList)  {
        List<Account> matchingAccount = [Select id,Chris_Account_Number__c from Account where 
                                         chris_account_number__c  = :P.Account_ref_ext_id__c];
        for ( Account A : matchingAccount) {
            if (P.Account_Ref_Ext_ID__c == A.Chris_Account_Number__c) {
                Properties__c Pr  = new Properties__c(Id = p.Id);   
                Pr.Provider__c = A.id;
                PropToUpdate.add(Pr);
            }
        }                 
     } 

    Update PropToUpdate;
  }
}
```

Comment: This is probably a better fit over at [codereview](https://codereview.stackexchange.com)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is typically solved with the [aggregate-query-update](https://sfdcfox.blogspot.com/2017/03/the-aggregate-query-update-pattern.html) pattern, which I wrote about a few years back. To do so, we follow three steps.

## 1 Aggregate

Gather the values we want to query.

```
Map<String, Id> extIds = new Map<String, Id>();
for(Properties__c record: newPropertiesList) {
  extIds.put(record.Account_Ref_Ext_Id__c, null);
}
```

## 2 Query

```
for(Account record: [SELECT Chris_Account_Number__c FROM Account WHERE Chris_Account_number__c IN :extIds.keySet()]) {
  extIds.put(record.Chris_Account_Number__c, record.Id);
}
```

## 3 Update

```
for(Properties__c record: newPropertiesList) {
  record.Provider__c = extIds.get(record.Account_Ref_Ext_Id__c);
}
```

Note that we can do this in a *before insert* and *before update* record, thus avoiding a recursive trigger loop. Always consider placing updates to the current record in a **before** trigger.

Comment: No matter what, I can always count on @sfdcfox

Comment: +1 @sfdcfox.. Nice!!

Comment: +1 @sfdcfox that's a nice and optimized solution by avoiding an additional `set`